# mysterios malloc error during run time

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to write a code to find out the length of the longest repeating substring in a given string.

The code is as follows.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<limits>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;


class trienode
{   
    private:
        int value;
        trienode *child[156];
    public:
        trienode()
        {
            value=0;
            for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            { 
                child[i]=NULL;
            }
        }
        void  insert(string str,int *,int *);
};      


class trie
{   
    private:
        trienode *head;
        int max;
    public:
        trie(string str) 
        {   
            head=new trienode();
            max=0;
            insert(str);
        }
        void insert(string);
        int getmax();
};  

void trie::insert(string str)
{
    int n=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int result=0;
        int set=0;
        cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;
        cout << "inside trie insert" <<str.substr(i)<< " " << str<<endl;
        cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;
        head->insert(str.substr(i),&set,&result);
        cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;
        if(result>max)
            max=result;
    }
}

void trienode::insert(string str,int *set,int *res)
{
    cout << "inside trienode insert" <<endl;
    if(str.length()>0)
    {
        if(str.length()==1)
            value=1;
        if(child[str.at(0)]!=NULL)
        {
            *set=1;
            child[str.at(0)]=new trienode();
        }
        else
        {
            if(!set)
                *res++;
            child[str.at(0)]->insert(str.substr(1),set,res);
        }
    }
}

int trie::getmax()
{
    return max;
}
int main()
{
    //char arr1[]="ATCGATCGA";
    trie t("ATCGATCGA");
    cout << t.getmax() <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this program.The following runtime error was thrown.I could not find any mistake in code.

```
malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have pointed out where exactly the error was seen.

The error was seen in this piece of code.

```
void trie::insert(string str)
    {
        int n=str.length();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int result=0;
            int set=0;
            cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;
            cout << "inside trie insert" <<str.substr(i)<< " " << str<<endl;
            cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;
            head->insert(str.substr(i),&set,&result);
            cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;
            if(result>max)
                max=result;
        }
    }
```

The first cout `cout << "inside trie insert" <<str<<endl;` is successfull.

The second cout `cout << "inside trie insert" <<str.substr(i)<< " " << str<<endl;` 
is where the error is seen.

Some one please help me out as I am stuck at this problem.

Thanks..

Comment: The size of the `trienode::child` array should be 256.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are having problems is because you've declared `child` as a vector with only `156` elements, yet you access up to `256`in your `for` loop. That cascades a whole lot of potential undefined behaviour.